# Condition Check with specific week start day

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to check whether a particular day is present in currentweek. **But I would prefer for my week to be from Sunday to Saturday**. As of now week is from Monday to Sunday. This is my query:

```
SELECT count(d3.COL02) ,d3.COL01 from Table  d3 where TO_CHAR(d3.COL10, 'YYYYWW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYWW');
```

I'm new to oracle, so could somebody help with this?

Say

```
TableA contains following data:
ID,COL01,COL02,COL10
1,199,10,28-07-18
2,199,10,29-07-18
3,199,20,30-07-18
4,199,20,31-07-18
```

exceuting query `SELECT count(d3.COL02) ,d3.COL01 from TableA d3 where TO_CHAR(d3.COL10, 'YYYYWW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYWW') group by d3.COL01;`

gives output

```
count(COL02),COL01
2,199
```

But expecting output:

```
count(COL02),COL01
4,199
```

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please post some sample data and needed result?

Comment: @Aleksej:will do

Comment: Just add `1` to your date when you make comparison.

Comment: your output is correct check the calender :-) its should be two.28th and 29th july comes in previous months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this query:

```
with tableA(id, col01, col02, col10) as (
    select 1, 199, 10, date '2018-07-28' from dual union all
    select 2, 199, 10, date '2018-07-29' from dual union all
    select 3, 199, 20, date '2018-07-30' from dual union all
    select 4, 199, 20, date '2018-07-31' from dual )
select d3.col10, 
       to_char(col10, 'day', 'nls_date_language=English') day, 
       to_char(col10, 'yyyyww') yw,
       to_char(col10 + 1, 'yyyyww') yw1
  from tableA d3
```

Result:

```
COL10       DAY       YW     YW1
----------- --------- ------ ------
2018-07-28  saturday  201830 201830
2018-07-29  sunday    201830 201831
2018-07-30  monday    201831 201831
2018-07-31  tuesday   201831 201831
```

Column `YW` is what you have now, when you add one day to date you assign Sunday to next week. So change your condition to:

```
where to_char(d3.col10 + 1, 'yyyyww') = to_char(sysdate + 1, 'yyyyww')
```

Comment: Is this solution specific to only 2018 or would it be correct even for dates in years 2016,2015 or even 2022?

Comment: @Raymond - the only references to 2018 are in the CTE used to provide your sample data, The actual query isn't specific to any year...

Comment: Do you need to add 1 to `sysdate` too - otherwise a query run on Sunday will get the wrong result, I think? (But my head hurts so not sure...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - yes, you are right even with headache. I made short test and it seems ok now.

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
select  count(*)from TableA d3 where to_char(d3.col10,'IW')=to_char(sysdate,'IW');
```

and the output will be 2 itself because 28 and 29 july comes in previous months.